# What would cause a parent table error midway through posting the same rows?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

Can someone tell me why after successfully entering rows (INSERT INTO), using the same INSERT template, rows start to be declined because of a parent table error?

*The parent and child tables*:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE nm_order (
  2  orderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  3  customerID INT REFERENCES nm_customer(customerID) NOT NULL,
  4  orderDate DATE NOT NULL,
  5  orderStatus VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
  6  orderShippedDate DATE ) ;
```

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE nm_orderLine (
  2  orderLineID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  3  orderID INT REFERENCES nm_order(orderID),
  4  productCode VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES nm_product(productCode),
  5  quantity NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  6  unitPrice NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL ) ;
```

*Successful rows and failure....*

```
SQL> INSERT INTO nm_orderLine (
  2  orderLineID, orderID, productCode, quantity, unitPrice)
  3  VALUES (5, 4, 'R03515', 1, 5.99) ;

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO nm_orderLine (
  2  orderLineID, orderID, productCode, quantity, unitPrice)
  3  VALUES (6, 5, 'R03669', 1, 8.99) ;

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO nm_orderLine (
  2  orderLineID, orderID, productCode, quantity, unitPrice)
  3  VALUES (7, 6, 'IM657', 1, 12.99) ;
INSERT INTO nm_orderLine (
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BISUSER.SYS_C009576) violated - parent key not
found
```

Several rows worked and then O started receiving this error using the same template. Can anyone see something wrong with the rejected statements? I cannot. Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the child row you are trying to insert does not have a parent: the foreign key relationship prohibits this situation:

```
CREATE TABLE nm_orderLine (
    ...
    orderID INT REFERENCES nm_order(orderID),
    ...
)
```

You need `order_id` `6` to be inserted in parent table `nm_order` before you can insert a referencing row in child table `nm_orderLine`.